# Suppress "Part" in report

Tags: parts, report

How do I suppress "Part" in the following MWE? I would like it to say "I Thesis" and "II Included papers" instead of "Part I Thesis" and "Part II Included Papers".

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\part{Thesis}
\part{Included Papers}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just redefining `\partname` to do nothing is not sufficient, because of the space inserted between the part name and the number, which is not suppressed.

A kludge is to redefine `\partname` to gobble the next token:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\partname}{\@gobble}
\makeatother
```

because it is used in `\@part` as

```
\partname\nobreakspace\thepart
```

However, a better way is to patch `\@part`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}{\partname\nobreakspace}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\part{Thesis}
\part{Included Papers}

\end{document}
```

[image]